# How do I disable the white flashing on Facebook on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

A few pre-requisites out of the way: I'm on iOS version 11.02 on an iPhone6s with FaceBook version 144.0 (all software is current and has been rebooted.)

I've noticed that at times any action showers me with white flashes. When I say flash I am referring to the area of the images, photos and buttons. I don't believe the camera flash ever activates during this.

When I scroll and see a picture - flash. When I scroll and see a video - flash. When I click on a like button or whatever, flash.

This seems to be tied in with their mystery algorithm to reward users for using the applications so they keep coming back. It is not a persistent thing. I cannot reproduce this behavior as it is done behind the scenes kinda like how you get a bunch of baloons of the likes group of emoticons.

I would like to disable this kind of behavior. I've done a search in the [FB help center](https://www.facebook.com/help/1075880512458213/?helpref=hc_fnav) but no results. I have gone through most things under Account Settings: > General, Photos, Video etc & News Feed Preferences.

Not seeing anything.

Does anyone know how I can disable this behavior?

Comment: Does it only happen when using the Facebook app?  When you say 'flash', do you mean the camera flash goes off or the screen flashes all white?

Comment: Updated the question for clarity. I believe it's the screen itself that flashes. Kind of like how you can set the mac os to flash on notification (an accessibility feature). I think more people have experienced this when playing steam games.

Comment: @fsb Yes, it is the Facebook that is doing this. Not the system.